# How to check all members of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a text-based survival simulator that uses an array of `Entity`s. The `Entity` class contains data about each entity, such as energy, hydration, and morale. I'm starting to wrap up the project but I have a problem. In order to write a `checkStatus()` method, I need to have an if statement that checks for Entity[].isAlive on all entities, even if I don't know how long the array is. In short, **how can I use an if statement to check for the value of *all* members of an array**? I know I will probably have to use a `for` loop to iteratively check the members, with the `array.getLength`. So far I can only check variables in single classes. I have seen similar questions but they don't quite get what I'm looking for.

P.S. I'm using basic Java, with no frameworks or libraries.

Pseudo-code that demonstrates what I'm looking for

```
if Entity[ALL-MEMBERS].isAlive {
    gameOver = true;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 6, 7, and 8:

```
public boolean areAllAlive(Entity[] entities) {
    if(entities == null || entities.length == 0) {
        return false; //?
    }
    for(Entity e : entities) {
       if(!e.isAlive()) {
          return false;
       }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Java 8, using streams/functions:

```
public boolean areAllAlive(Entity[] entities) {
    if(entities == null || entities.length == 0) {
        return false; //?
    }
    return Arrays.stream(entities).allMatch(e -> e.isAlive());
}
```

Comment: To make it even more Java 8-friendly you can replace `e->e.isAlive()` with a method reference: `Entity::isAlive`

Comment: `isAlive` is not a method; it is a `boolean`, updated by other classes.

Answer (score 0):

First, since you probably don't know the number of Entities you are going to use before hand an ArrayList is probably a better choice. Then yes, you should use an enhanced for loop:

```
List<Entity> list = new ArrayList<>();
public void addEntities(){
    //add Entities here
}

public boolean ifAlive(){
    for (Entity e: list){
        if (!e.isAlive()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming array is your entity's array, try this.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 Entity entity = array[i];
 if (entity.isAlive) {
    gameOver = true;
    //your code here
 }
}
```